# What is the output of this code using a stack?

Tags: java, stack, peek

We're learning stacks in Intermediate Programming and we're using Practice-IT! for coding examples.  I'm stuck on this one question:
 
"Write a method splitStack that takes a stack of integers as a parameter and splits it into negatives and non-negatives. The numbers in the stack should be rearranged so that all the negatives appear on the bottom of the stack and all the non-negatives appear on the top. In other words, if after this method is called you were to pop numbers off the stack, you would first get all the nonnegative numbers and then get all the negative numbers. It does not matter what order the numbers appear in as long as all the negatives appear lower in the stack than all the non-negatives. You may use a single queue as auxiliary storage."
I tried writing some code for it but it's saying it's wrong.  I don't know where I went wrong since I'm learning this for the first time.

```java
public Stack<Integer> splitStack(Stack<Integer> intSt)
    {
        Stack posSt = new Stack();
        Stack negSt = new Stack();

      for(int i = 0; i<intSt.size(); i++)
        {
            intSt.pop();
            if (intSt.peek() < 0)
            {
                negSt.push(intSt);
            } 
            else
            {
                posSt.push(intSt);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<negSt.size(); i++)
        {
            negSt.pop();
            intSt.push();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<posSt.size(); i++)
        {
            posSt.pop();
            intSt.push();
        }
        return  intSt;
    }
```

Comment: Can you check what are your actual results for a given input? I think I spotted the error, but it seems you don't have a way to debug your program properly

Comment: It's not compiling.  The error it gives me is "You are passing the wrong type/number of parameters when calling a method" at lines 22 (intSt.push();) and 28 (intSt.push();)

Comment: yea, because push requires the integer that is going to be pushed like intSt.push(4); pushes 4 into the stack

Comment: Ohhhhh.  I gotcha.  That makes sense.  So I should put intSt.push(negSt) for the negative values?

Comment: you should push an integer, not a stack, negSt is an entire stack, not an integer

Comment: What editor are you using to edit your code? A good IDE should make these issues obvious, so you are either using something like notepad to edit your code, or you haven learned how to use your IDE properly.

Comment: I'm using the IDE on Practice-IT

Comment: Practice-IT gives you syntax highlighting, but it doesn't give you auto-complete and debugging features, good IDE would show you the method's documentation when you select it on the auto-complete, such as: "pop(): Removes the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as the value of this function.", and would also notice you called pop() without an assignment and suggest you to assign the returned value to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the code so I'm gonna tackle them one by one but first, I'm gonna talk about the root of them: you need to develop your code on an IDE that supports intellisense and debugging, for java, the one I like the most is IntelliJ.

With a good IDE, you'd have seem that:

1. pop() has a return value, so when you pop, you should store the popped value like int `poppedValue = intSt.pop();`
2. push requires a value, so if you want to push the value you just popped from intSt you should go with `negSt.push(poppedValue);` (you push poppedValue, not the intSt)
3. after fixing all your pushes and pops, the program would still give wrong results because `intSt.size()` changes as you pop the stack, so your for would exit before the stack was empty and thus, would not split the whole stack, you could fix this by changing your fors into whiles as in `while(intSt.size() > 0)`

The last one would be the hardest one to catch, so I'm gonna suggest you some homework that will help you start finding all those issues by yourself:

- Download an actual java IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse or Netbeans).
- Understand those tools intellisense (all of them bring up a context menu when you hit period '.' after a variable name, that menu contains a lot of information about methods and properties of the variable)
- Learn to set up a breakpoint.
- Learn step-over, step-into and step-out.
- Learn how to use the "watch" window.

After that, will never want to work directly on a site anymore, you'll always develop on an IDE and then copy your work somewhere else after it's done, it really saves you a lot of time.